# Getting error "function week(timestamp without time zone) does not exist"

Tags: sql, date, ruby-on-rails-4

I was following this example [How do I change the records being displayed on the page with buttons on the page (RoR)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641290/how-do-i-change-the-records-being-displayed-on-the-page-with-buttons-on-the-page/3641430#3641430) and managed to get the Daily filter working but when trying to set it up for the Weekly filter I get the error
PG::Error: ERROR: function week(timestamp without time zone) does not exist

I figured the WEEK function should work automatically as the DATE function did but that's not the case.

model

```
def self.popularToday
    reorder('votes desc').find_with_reputation(:votes, :all, { :conditions => ["DATE(microposts.created_at) = DATE(NOW())"]})
end
def self.popularWeekly
    reorder('votes desc').find_with_reputation(:votes, :all, { :conditions => ["WEEK(microposts.created_at) = WEEK(NOW())"]})
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<form action="" method="get">
  <fieldset>
     <button type="submit" name="show" value="daily">Today</button>
     <button type="submit" name="show" value="weekly">This week</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

controller

```
when "daily"
          Kaminari.paginate_array(Micropost.popularToday).page(params[:page]).per(25)
when "weekly"
          Kaminari.paginate_array(Micropost.popularWeekly).page(params[:page]).per(25)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need:

```
"SELECT EXTRACT(WEEK FROM TIMESTAMP  microposts.created_at)"
```

This will retrieve the week number based on the created at timestamp in postgres.

Documentation: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-datetime.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried changing it to this SELECT EXTRACT(WEEK FROM TIMESTAMP 'microposts.created_at') but now I'm getting the error "PG::Error: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "microposts.created_at""

Comment: There shouldn't be quotes around microposts.created_at. Only the sql statement itself should be within quotes.

Comment: When I removed the quotes I got a syntax error but I finally figured it out. Your original format kind of confused me since the condition I'm trying to build has 2 sides to it. This gave me the correct results `"EXTRACT(WEEK FROM microposts.created_at) = EXTRACT(WEEK FROM now())"`

Answer (score 2):

The name of the table that has my timestamp without time zone data is called create_date. I used EXTRACT(WEEK FROM create_date) and it worked.